How to make an App to the default phone app
I am new to Android app development. So I'm wondering what I need to do to make my app the default phone app. If anyone can help me I would be very grateful
Best regards Raphael Schneider
A photo of the default phone app settings 
I've already tried a few things in the Android Manifest, but that didn't work.
Chatgpt couldn't help me either

You can't do it programmatically.  Default apps need to be set by the user.  This is because otherwise every app would make itself the default app.  Unless you're asking how to make your app an option for the user to pick?

I know, but the permissions are granted and I'm just wondering how the app can say that it can be a standard phone app, so to speak

Ok so you want it to be listed as an option.  That's a manifest thing.  It should be described at https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/telecom/dialer-app. I believe the important thing is the connection service and the intent filter for it in the manifest

To list your app, as a dialer, so that the OS, can list it in the above settings page
You can declare the permission MANAGE_OWN_CALLS in your Manifest file. You can read about it here
And you can ask the user to set your app as the default dialer. As Gabe pointed out, you cannot do that programatically, but you can prompt the user to do so
Reference code taken from here
Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER).putExtra(
        TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME,
        activity.packageName
    ).apply {
        if (resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val rm: RoleManager? = activity.getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
                if (rm?.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER) == true) {
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    activity.startActivityForResult(
                        rm.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER),
                        REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER
                    )
                }
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                activity.startActivityForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER)
            }
        } else {
            activity.toastShort(R.string.no_contacts_found)
        }
    }


Thank u very much
